# Chef: private supermarket cookbook directly on server

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, berkshelf

I have a cookbook which is available on a private chef supermarket and I have 4 chef servers which need this cookbook to be available so that corresponding nodes can consume it.

We can use `berks install` and `berks upload` multiple times to achieve this. Is there a simpler way to do this?

If it is not possible, why does chef not allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have 4 **different** chef servers, then i assume that you are using [4 **different** keys](https://docs.chef.io/chef_private_keys.html) for authentication when you interact with the chef server. this implies that you have [4 **different** configurations](https://docs.chef.io/knife_setup.html) which is used in the process.

there is no tool which i know of that for each configuration it uploads the cookbook to chef server.

so for your question, you should upload your cookbook to each chef server individually.